# TypeScript overload cannot see a type that is defined in the implementation

Tags: typescript, overloading

In this example TypeScript reports "Cannot find name 'fnA'."  This is a simplified case.  I need to define the functions inside `fn` in the actual use case.  Is there any way to get it to see fnA?

```
function fn(a: true): typeof fnA; // "Cannot find name 'fnA'."
function fn(a: false): typeof fnB;
function fn(a: boolean): typeof fnA | typeof fnB {

    function fnA() { console.log(a);};
    function fnB() { console.log(a);};
    if (a) {
        return fnA;
    }
    else {
        return fnB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you unsimplify this a little so that `typeof fnA` and `typeof fnB` are not identical types?  Right now they're both `()=>void`.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXz81m) perhaps?

Comment: No, you can't do what you're asking; there is a feature request for this at [ms/TS#48543](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48543) marked as "awaiting more feedback" so if you want to see this happen you could upvote it and comment about why you need it, and why workarounds aren't sufficient.  The workaround here being just manually defining types and annotating things like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOx9rN). Does this fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?